# Tool for downloading music playlists

Tags: music, automation, download-manager

There are several freely available music APIs listed here:
http://musicmachinery.com/music-apis/

I'm looking for a tool for Linux or Windows that can take as an input, the name/link of a playlist from one of the "Discovery / Playlisting" APIs from that site (or other popular music discovery service).

It will then go to the "Audio Content" APIs and try to download each song on the playlist in the highest quality available, adding all the relevant metadata.

It will output a list of the songs it could not find, and I will manually try to download them.

Does anyone know of a tool/script like this? It shouldn't cost more than 100 bucks.

If not, how about libraries that work with music discovery/music download sites so I can build one myself.

Comment: Targetting all APIs make the question too broad. Would you mind restricting to a single API?

Comment: It's more like pick one rather that support all.